# Return a mapping in a getAll function

Tags: solidity, remix, mapping

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract User {
    mapping(uint=>address) addresses;
    uint addressRegistryCount;   

    function set(address userAddress) public {
        addresses[addressRegistryCount] = userAddress;
        addressRegistryCount++;
    }

    function get(address userAddress) public view returns (uint) {
        for (uint i = 0; i <= addressRegistryCount; i++) {
            if(addresses[i] == userAddress)
                return i;
        }
    }

    /*function getAll() {

    }*/
}
```

In this contract I have a function called getAll. Inside that function I´m trying to return the full mapping of users. How can I make that?

Comment: If you want to fetch it from the off-chain, then just add `public` before `addresses`, and you've got yourself a "getAll" function (which you can invoke from the off-chain via `addresses()`).

Comment: @goodvibration Adding the `public` identifier doesn't result in a `getAll` function. It gives you a public function which takes index as input and returns only one element of mapping.

Comment: Sample: https://gist.github.com/samanshahmohamadi/d0d43034e45ccadfd48ce97ed0bd1aba

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can't return a `mapping` directly. What you can do is to make an array and add all `address` values that is stored in the `addresses` mapping to it. Then return that array.

```
function getAll() public view returns (address[] memory){
    address[] memory ret = new address[](addressRegistryCount);
    for (uint i = 0; i < addressRegistryCount; i++) {
        ret[i] = addresses[i];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: You actually can return a `mapping`, so long as it maps types of fixed length (and in the example above, `uint` and `address` are such).

Comment: Could you provide an example code?

Comment: See my comment to the question.

Comment: Works fine thx  bouth ;D

Comment: Your're welcome ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a mapping, you can return 2 arrays. Take a look at this working example...

```
function getAvailableMintsForUser(WhitelistStorage storage self) public view returns (uint256[] memory, uint8[] memory) {
    uint256 balance = self.contract.balanceOf(msg.sender);
    uint256[] memory tokenIds = new uint256[](balance);
    uint8[] memory available = new uint8[](balance);
    for(uint256 i = 0 ; i < balance ; i++) {
        tokenIds[i] = self.chroma.tokenOfOwnerByIndex(msg.sender, i);
        available[i] = calcAvailableMintsPerTokenId(self, tokenIds[i]);
    }
    return (tokenIds, available);
}
```